# Keep writing elements into an iframe even after its redirection to different URLs

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know how to write into an iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Writer</title>
    <style>
        textarea,
        iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 800px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="ta" oninput="writeIt();"></textarea>
    <iframe id="frm"></iframe>
    <script>
        function writeIt() {
            var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
            var frm = document.getElementById('frm');
            var frmDoc = frm.contentDocument;
            frmDoc.open();
            frmDoc.write(ta.value);
            frmDoc.close();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/VY7uw/)**

There's a problem, though. Enter the following into the textarea:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">Example.com</a>
```

Now click on the link, and then get back to the textarea to continue writing. It doesn't work anymore due to the cross-origin restriction. Is there any way in this case to continue writing?

Note: I've found three similar applications that seem to function as I wish. I wonder how they work differently from my demo and what changes I need to make in my code:

- https://thimble.webmaker.org/
- http://codepen.io/pen/
- http://cssdeck.com/labs

Here's the code I tried on them:

```
<a href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B1iqp0kGPjWsVms5S3JzaUZJYVk/page-template.html" target="_self">Page Template</a>
```

Comment: Since “writing” into the iframe in that way replaces the current document within the iframe completely, you might as well change its `src` back to a document from your own domain before you write anything new to it. Or replace the iframe element with a new, empty one.

Comment: Is that what you mean:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/VY7uw/1/). It gives an error in console and doesn't start writing immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. Either:

1. Force all off-site links to open in a new tab/window; or
2. Reclaim the iframe by setting its source to a local URL if it can no longer be written to.

The best solution will depend on your exact requirements.

*Update:* Having written and tested both, I think option 2 is best unless you have very specific requirements that make option 1 better.

**Option 1**

Taking the 'target new window' solution first, simply compare all links to the current domain and if they're off-site, automatically set the link target to a blank window.

**[See jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/dVXLm/1/)**

Javascript:

```
function setTargets() {
    var links = document.getElementById("frm").contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var currentDomain = "http://" + document.location.hostname;
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].href.indexOf(currentDomain) == -1) {
            links[i].target = "_blank";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="ta" onkeyup="writeIt();" onblur="setTargets();">Type here</textarea>
```

**Option 2**

Taking the 'reclaim the iframe' approach (better!), you'd simply wrap the attempt to write the iframe into a try/catch.

**[See jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/YWLep/1/)**

Javascript:

```
function writeIt() {
    var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
    var frm = document.getElementById('frm');
    try {
        var frmDoc = frm.contentDocument;
        frmDoc.open();
        frmDoc.write(ta.value);
        frmDoc.close();
    } 
    catch(err) {
        frm.src = "about:blank";
        setTimeout(writeIt,500);
    }
}
```

If you can replace the 'about:blank' with a real blank local page (e.g. blank.html) that might make it a bit more cross-browser compatible - I've only tested it in Chrome so far.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The second one seems nice. Can I use `onerror` event: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/VY7uw/6/)?

Comment: Yes, using window.onerror seems to work nicely too. I don't suppose there's much to choose between them - the try/catch will be more specific to the original problem, whereas the onerror could potentially fire for other error cases (which may or may not be a good thing). Seems fairly robust either way.

Comment: One more question please: in most sources I have seen `catch(e)` rather than `catch(err)`. Does it make a difference? Is there any specification?

Comment: It makes no difference. It's just the variable that stores the error, so you could do alert(err.message) if you wanted to. There's a good summary here if you're interested. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: I just got to try it in Safari 7 through an emulator and it seems to throw an error in console although it works with no problem: the iframe redirects to Example.com and then comes back to the original origin when you start typing. It seems to be a bug in Safari.